# How "Service Bus Connect EAI and EDI" will be helpful to integrate on-primise SAP?

Tags: edi, servicebus, eai

I just started to explore the Service Bus Connect EAI and EDI, and I am looking the solution/middleware which fulfill following scenario.

We have a product and we are looking to integrate our product with SAP/Oracle Business Suite/Sieble/Oracle/SQL Server at client on-premises. So we should only do the configuration and minimal installation to expose the end-points at client on-premises.

How "Service Bus Connect EAI and EDI" will be helpful in this case?

As far as I understand "Service Bus Connect EAI and EDI", there are lots of installation we requires to do, is my undesrstanding correct?

if not how we can use this middleware?

Thanks in advance.
-Ripal

Comment: If you are looking at a middleware solution that will help integrate with all the systems you are looking for, and be a Microsoft based solution, you should look here: https://liaison.com/products/transform/delta  There is a runtime solution that you could deploy at your client's system.

Answer (score 0):

this is Harish from Azure Service Bus EAI & EDI team .

The integration to SAP/Oracle Business Suite/Sieble/Oracle/SQL Server at client on-premises can be done using Service Bus Connect feature we have . It provides a simple and configuration-only experience to do so in quick time.

You can download the binaries from here (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17691) and the installation guide is here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh689760.aspx).

In you have any question/clarification or run into any issue or then you may post it on our public forum here (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/servicebuslabs/threads ) and we will get back to you very shortly.

Hope this helps,
- Harish Kumar Agarwal

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 

But I don't think it will be helpful to us as a solution, as I mentioned in my question, it may require to purchase all of the softwares (for client/by client) mentioned in the provided link. 

Let me know if I understood something wrong.

I have already posted this question to public forums also.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/servicebuslabs/threads?page=1

Thanks

Ripal Mehta